# Working with Highlights on Solr 6.4.1

Tags: solr, lucene, highlight

I am running Solr 6.4.1 on a Windows 7 machine, with Chrome for testing query URLs currently.

I have set up and got working an index on a set of test documents - a small number of of webpages saved as Docx files in a folder. I can get basic queries working and am now trying to get highlighting working.

I have not modified the schema in any way - simply indexed the folder into a Core called test.

The following query and highlights as I expect:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?hl=on&hl.fl=meta_author&q=steven&wt=xml&fl=meta_author
```

and returns

```
...<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="C:\Users\steven\Documents\Indexing\Dungeon Arena Building.docx">
<arr name="meta_author">
<str><em>steven</em></str>
</arr>
</lst>...
```

However if I change the fields try and highlight where the term is found in the name of the document it does not work in this way.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?hl=on&hl.fl=dc_title&q=gothic&wt=xml&fl=dc_title
```

returns

```
...<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="C:\Users\steven\Documents\Indexing\Basic Gothic Dungeon.docx"/>
<lst name="C:\Users\steven\Documents\Indexing\Dungeon Arena Building.docx"/>
</lst>...
```

The results are correct but it does not highlight the identified data fields.

Are there some rules around the available fields that can be highlighted or do I need to amend something in the schema?

For context I aim to bring over all the file content into the index so that I can then present back the match in context of the surrounding text for the users to see.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the field is stored for `dc_title` .

In your schema your field should look like(field type can be different, as you defined, but set stored=true), after modification, reindex doc and search again.

```
<field name="dc_title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I have had a look at the files and find only a managed-schema (no extension) in the conf folder with a large "Do not Edit" warning. 
Ignoring the warning and updating via the instructions you provided and re-indexing still returns the same results with the highlight block but no actual highlight details to parse. I am guessing I just need to create a schema.xml and add this into the folder by copying out the content of the managed-schema but can you confirm?

Comment: Further to this I tried out adding in a clone of the managed schema as schema.xml and amending the content as stated but this did not appear to make any difference in the highlighting. Not sure where i am off here.